# Taking multiple geodatabases created in first tool and using those as output locations for second tool in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I created a ModelBuilder tool that selects the information from my feature class table, groups it by its unique attribute, and makes a file geodatabase and new feature class from that selection. There are 10 geodatabases and feature classes created in total.

That tool works fine, but the issue I'm having now is redoing this process with a new feature class layer to add to each of the existing created 10 geodatabases and their FCs.

When I run both tools together, the first one creates the 10 unique geodatabases and their FCs, but the second tool puts all of its newly selected and created feature classes into only the last geodatabase. I tried using the first model (test) and adding my second model (ToEdit) as a tool, with the output being GDB from test, but that makes no difference, and puts all the results from the second tool (ToEdit) into my first created GDB from test tool.

How do I join my two tools in a way that lets the second tool separate its feature classes into the 10 geodatabases?

[image: Tool that works]
[image: Second tool]

[image: Trying to combine]